# Retrieving IP and mac addresses

Tags: java, macos, network-programming, ip

I want to get IP Address and MAC address of my pc. I used the following code to do so:

```
InetAddress ip;
try {

    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (SocketException e){

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

It worked too, but some times the same code prints IP as 127.0.0.1 and doesn't print any mac address. How come?

Comment: this code is running on a applet or java app at client or on your server?

Answer (score 4):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address which always exists (*).

A better way of getting the value would be getting all the network interfaces (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()) and filtering out the ones whose IP begins with `127`.

(*) Except on windows machines where the network cable is disconnected...

Comment: i want to identify client's pc... here i m getting mac address from ip  i got InetAddress.getLocalHost().. which is sometimes giving loopback address.... is there any way of gettig mac without ip